# SimpleDateFormat parsing is not correct

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I'm using `SimpleDateFormat` to parse Date String ase bellow:

```
final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD");
System.out.println(formatter.parse(firstDate));
```

And for String "`2011-04-02"` i got after parsing `"Sun Jan 02 00:00:00 EET 2011"` so Month is Jan there but must be Apr.

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DD` is day in year. You need `dd` (lowercase) instead, which is day in month.

See [documentation of SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Try: `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`.

`DD` is day of year, that's why you got 2nd of January.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(formatter.parse(firstDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your date format incorrect. use `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

```
final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(formatter.parse("2011-04-02"));
```

Live [Demo](http://ideone.com/9CkehV)